# Running cp -r ~/.ipython ~/some/path/.ipython a second time creates ~/some/path/.ipython/.ipython. How to prevent that?

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I am using a script to copy directories to a specified location. When I run `cp -r ~/.ipython ~/some/path/.ipython` the `.ipython` dir is copied as expected to the specified location. But when I run this command again `~/some/path/.ipython/.ipython` is created.

I understand that this is recursive, but what command copies a dir while for subsequent calls of that command prevent a dir is recursively created inside that same dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you've noticed, nothing prevent the `cp` command to create a new `.ipython` dir inside every other `.ipython` dir.

If you are using it in a script which you run repeatedly, the best approach to avoid the problem is not to use `cp` but `rsync`:

```
rsync -vua ~/.ipython/ ~/some/path/.ipython/
```

NB, the trailing `/` at the end of path is significant for `rsync`. If you are trying it out, don't forget to add that.

**EDIT**:  Kruug's answer should be working as well, but `rsync` will yield better performance, especially when you are doing it repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

```
cp -r ~/.ipython/ ~/some/path/.ipython
```

add the slash, it copies the contents of the directory

Comment: Could you also do `cp -r ~/.ipython ~/some/path/`?

Comment: Could you make a separate answer of this Kruug?

Comment: @Rich Homolka : Running that command repeatedly still creates a new `.ipython` dir inside every other `.ipython` dir.

Comment: why are you running the command repeatedly?

Comment: @MattDMo Because I'm using it in a script which I run repeatedly.

Comment: I guess the question is - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I know there is an other way to get what I want, but it would just be a lot of work. Kruug's answer worked so the problem is solved.